# When rolling a die $N$ times, what is the probability of an $X$ appearing before the last $Y$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, combinatorics

So a valid state is when there are *both* $X$ and $Y$ in the roll sequence, and the lowest index of an $X$ is smaller than the biggest index of a $Y$.

In particular, if after $N$ rolls, there is no $X$ or no $Y$, this does not count as a success.

### For example

$N = 5$, $X = 1$, $Y = 2$ (Roll dice 5 times, 1 appearing before 2)

- 1 4 2 3 1
- 2 1 3 4 2

I would like the formula such that we can calculate the probability given $N$, $p_X$ and $p_Y$.

The closest I got is this :

```py
def prob(N,pX,pY):
    res = 0
    for i in range(0,N):
        res+=((1-pX)**i)*pX*(N-i-1)*pY
    return res
```

Comment: Is your condition fulfilled if (1) X appears, but not Y, or if (2) Y appears, but not X, or if (3) neither one appears?

Comment: All 3 conditions are not fullfilled. X and Y should appear atleast once.

Comment: Is the die 6 sided?

Comment: @MichaelChernick: given that $P(X)$ and $P(Y)$ are inputs, I do not expect the die to be six sided *or* fair.

Comment: For any fixed N there is always a probability (possibly small) that one or both of X and Y don't occur in the sequence. Technically X doesn't occur before Y or Y doesn't occur before X in those situations. If I read your response right you want to condition on both X and Y occurring at least once. To compute the conditional probability you do need to calculate the probabilities of the 3 cases Stephen points out.

Comment: You can specify P(X) and P(Y) and if you specify them to be unequal then of course the die is not fair. But there as still two problems as I see it. You need to know the probabilities for the other faces and you need to know the number of faces on the die. The obvious but not yet specified assumption is that trials are independent.

Comment: I am going to vote to close because I think the problem is not yet well defined. Without these conditioned specified I think it is not clear what question we need to answer.

Comment: I'll assume the die rolls are independent, as die rolls typically are, and write up the answer for this case. Can we all please hold off on the close-voting until I'm done? Thanks!

Comment: I assume the P(X) + P(Y) <1. I don't see under that circumstance how you can preclude the possibility that the die is 6 sided. But the number of sides makes a difference as to what the probabilities are for each sequence. So the number of sides must be specified.

Comment: for large $N$ I think it should be $\frac{P(X)}{P(X)+P(Y)}$

Comment: I didn't see your answer. How can you give an answer without making assumptions that the OP didn't provide. I already voted to close. If the question is closed I will be willing to vote to reopen if the OP specifies the number of sides and if the number is >2 I still think the probabilities for the other sides must be specified. I will accept the assumption of independent trials.

Comment: @MichaelChernick: I'd be interested in any comments on my answer below. I do not think it matters how many sides the die has - we are only interested in two specific outcomes and "everything else". The formula I provide worked well in simulations for $N=2$ and larger $N$. I may certainly have made a number of errors; it's 02:22am over here, and most fittingly, I already consumed 2 glasses of wine tonight, so I'll be off to bed and look forward to any comments I'll read tomorrow.

Comment: My understanding is that P(X) and P(Y) are respectively the probability of drawing X on any given trial and ditto for Y. I don't see how @probabilityislogic got the asymptotic result in his comment.

Comment: I cannot make any sense of this question.  Would anybody who has engaged in this dialog be able to contribute a clear statement of what exactly is being asked?  As an example of why I'm struggling, what happens if after $N$ rolls neither "Y" nor "X" appear?  Indeed, the question itself suggests there are *two* sets of rolls (maybe one is called "X" and the other "Y"?) being compared.

Comment: This question is very vague and needs to be updated. But, we can say at least state that the answer should not be $P (X)/(P(X)+P(Y))$. This is because the OP is asking for the probability that the *first* X occurs before the *last* Y. Those specifications first/last are important. Imagine N very large then the probability should approach 1 for one or more Y's (including the last Y) to occur after the first X (which means the reverse, an X, including the first, to occur before the last Y also has probability approaching 1)

Comment: I nominate to reopen as well Stephen's expression seems good enough to handle it. The only ambiguity is what to do when no $Y$ appears or no $X$ but it seems to boil down to the same treatment (and just some extra calculations for those additional cases)

Comment: As to what happens when after $N$ rolls, there is no $X$ or no $Y$: this situation does not count as a success. [See the OP's comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/423569/when-rolling-a-dice-n-times-what-is-the-probability-of-an-x-appearing-before/423572?noredirect=1#comment790395_423569) in reply to [me asking this exact question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/423569/when-rolling-a-dice-n-times-what-is-the-probability-of-an-x-appearing-before/423572?noredirect=1#comment790394_423569). I'll edit this into the question and hope for reopening, too.

Answer (score 5):

Here you go:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{N-1}(1-p_Y)^{k-1}p_Y\big(1-(1-p_X)^{N-k}\big). $$

I sure hope that makes you happy. [probabilityislogic turned this into the following only-slightly-less-intimidating closed form](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/423569/when-rolling-a-dice-n-times-what-is-the-probability-of-an-x-appearing-before/423572?noredirect=1#comment790475_423572):

$$
1-(1-p_X)^{N-1}-p_X\big[(1-p_Y)^{N-1}-(1-p_X)^{N-1}\big]\frac{1-p_Y}{p_X-p_Y} \quad\text{if }p_X\neq p_Y
$$

$$
1-(1-p+Np)(1-p)^{N-1}\quad\text{if }p_X=p_Y=:p.
$$
The first idea is that the probability of a "successful" outcome ("both $X$ and $Y$ are present in the roll, and an $X$ appears before the last $Y$") is equivalent to "both $X$ and $Y$ are present in the roll, and an $X$ appears *after* the *first* $Y$". The equivalence lies simply in counting from the back instead of from the front. (This just simplifies the summation indices above, you can easily work with the original formulation, it's just a little messier.)

Let's work with this equivalent formulation. It can be disentangled as:

- there is some index $k\in\{1, \dots, N-1\}$ (this is what we sum over) such that:
- there is no $Y$ for the $k-1$ first rolls (this is the $(1-p_Y)^{k-1}$ term) *and*
- the $k$-th roll is $Y$ (with probability $p_Y$) *and*
- there is at least one $X$ roll after that (this is the $\big(1-(1-p_X)^{N-k}\big)$ term: it's the complement of there being *no* $X$ in $N-k$ rolls).

The formula seems to work in simulations, where I played around with the `nn`, `px` and `py` parameters (in R):

```
nn <- 2
px <- .3
py <- .3

n_sims <- 1e4
n_x_before_y <- 0

for ( ii in 1:n_sims ) {
    roll <- sample(x=c("x","y","z"),size=nn,replace=TRUE,prob=c(px,py,1-px-py))
    if ( "x" %in% roll & "y" %in% roll) {
        if ( min(which(roll=="x"))<max(which(roll=="y")) ) {
            n_x_before_y <- n_x_before_y+1
        }
    }
}

n_x_before_y/n_sims


sum((1-py)^(0:(nn-2))*py*(1-(1-px)^((nn-1):1)))

if ( isTRUE(all.equal(px,py)) ) {
    cat(1-(1-px+nn*px)*(1-px)^(nn-1),"\n")
} else {
    cat(1-(1-px)^(nn-1)-px*((1-py)^(nn-1)-(1-px)^(nn-1))*(1-py)/(px-py),"\n")
}
```

This has been giving me the correct result, both for the sum form and for the closed form [probabilityislogic proposed](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/423569/when-rolling-a-dice-n-times-what-is-the-probability-of-an-x-appearing-before/423572?noredirect=1#comment790475_423572).

Of course, it does not matter whether the die is 3-, 6- or 27-sided - all we care about is the probabilities of the two events in question and "everything else", so for our purposes, we can collapse "everything else".

An interesting aspect that stumped me for a while is that the specific probabilities $p_X$ and $p_Y$ have a different impact for small and large $N$. If $N$ is small, e.g., $N=2$, then all we care is whether both $X$ and $Y$ are present in the roll at all. Conditional on that, $(X,Y)$ and $(Y,X)$ are equally likely, no matter how different $p_X$ and $p_Y$ are! But if $N$ grows, then both $X$ and $Y$ are more and more certainly present in the overall roll, and which one appears first depends of course on the ratio between $p_X$ and $p_Y$.

Overall, a nice little problem. Thanks!

Comment: Okay. I do see that your formula gives the probability that X occurs before Y and you can provide a similar formula for Y occurring before X. My argument missed the fact that you only needed to specify that one of the other sides occurred on specific trials and not which of those sides occurred.

Comment: I like the answer but I am still a little puzzled. Why don't you need to condition on the cases where only X never occurs in the N trials or Y never occurs or neither occurs?

Comment: Maybe I see the answer to my question. Is it that the 3rd term in the product handles  the conditioning?

Comment: note, you can simplify that formula a bit further by analytically evaluating the summation. The result is $$\frac{p_X}{p_Y+p_X}\left[1-(1-p_Y-p_X)^{N-1}\right] - (1-p_Y)^N\left[1-(1-\frac{p_X}{1-p_Y})^{N-1}\right]$$ The limit as $N\to\infty$ is $\frac{p_X}{p_Y+p_X}$

Comment: Your answer looks nice, but as stated in the question: "smallest index of X is smaller than the biggest index of Y ". So the only condition for a valid state is that an X appears before another Y in N rolls.

 So a state where Y happens before X and then Y again is also valid, while in your solution Y can't occur before X.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I was misled by "a symbol X appearing before symbol Y". I'll take a look and see whether I can salvage my idea, but only later today; I am a bit sleep-deprived. (Actually, I think I can simply turn everything around, counting from the back and exchanging $X$ and $Y$. Let me see...)

Comment: @MichaelChernick: the conditioning is handled implicitly by the second term (there must be an $X$) and the third one (there must be a $Y$ later on). I did play around with conditioning first and then writing out the conditional probability, but I didn't get anywhere - this is what I mean in my second-to-last paragraph.

Comment: OK, I edited the answer. It works well with simulations. (Note that I of course also changed the simulations.) Better?

Comment: I think if you allow the $k-1$ trials to include $Y$, your answer should account for the op's comment. Updating the expression gives $$1-(1-p_X)^{N-1} - p_X\left[(1-p_Y)^{N-1}-(1-p_X)^{N-1}\right]\frac{1-p_Y}{p_X-p_Y}$$ if $p_X\neq p_Y$ and value equal to $1-(1-p+Np)(1-p)^{N-1}$ if $p_X=p_Y=p$. In both cases the limiting value is $1$ as $N\to\infty$ (makes sense).  note, posting as a comment because you essentially have the answer already. happy for you to copy this in if you want :)

Comment: @probabilityislogic: if the first $k-1$ trials are allowed to include a $Y$, then the different events whose probability we sum over are not disjoint any more, so the sum would not be correct. Thanks for the updated closed form!

Comment: I voted to reopen.

Comment: I do not see the simplification in the indices. Why would this not work?

$$\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\underbrace{(1-p_X)^{k-1}p_X}_{P(\text{$X$ at $k$-th step})}\underbrace{\big(1-(1-p_Y)^{N-k}\big)}_{P(\text{some $Y$ between $k+1$-th and $N$-th step})}$$ which means that there is a symmetry in the answer, you can exchange $p_X$ and $p_Y$.

Comment: The simplification could go like: 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}(1-p_Y)^{k-1}p_Y - (1-p_X)^{N-1} p_Y \sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\left( \frac{1-p_Y}{1-p_X}\right)^{k-1} $$
becoming
$$1+\frac{p_X}{p_Y-p_X}(1-p_Y)^{N-1} + \frac{p_Y}{p_X-p_Y} (1-p_X)^{N-1} $$
which highlights the symmetry better